# MVVMCross Manual Bind in MvxFragment with MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using an implementation of Cheesebaron's MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter example that can be found here http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/07/fragments-and-viewpager-with-mvx.html

```
var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo>
          {

            new MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
            {
              FragmentType = typeof(JobDetailsView),
              Title = "Detail",
              ViewModel = ViewModel
            },
            new MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
            {
              FragmentType = typeof(JobFeaturesView),
              Title = "Info",
              ViewModel = ViewModel
            }
}
```

Within my JobDetailsView's OnCreateView, I can inflate my layout specified using BindingInflate and any bindings that I have specified in the XML layout work correctly.

I now have a requirement to bind some elements programmatically, which i have tried to do using CreateBindingSet, but the bindings do not work. I've tried a simple text property and a button click. Both of these work when specified in the XML.

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet(savedInstanceState);
        _view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.jobview_details, null);//jobview_withtabs_details

        var signatureCard = _view.FindViewById<CardFeature>(Resource.Id.signature_cardview);
        signatureCard.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_basecard_header_title).Text = "Signature";
        var signatureButton = signatureCard.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_basecard_footer).Text = "Capture";

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<JobDetailsView, JobWithTabsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(signatureButton).To(vm => vm.SignatureClickCommand);
        set.Apply();

        return _view;

    }
```

in my output window, i can see this, but i don't know what to do to fix it:

```
04-16 17:40:43.721 I/mono-stdout(27727): MvxBind:Error: 23.79 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
MvxBind:Warning: 23.80 Failed to create target binding for binding  for SignatureClickCommand
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 23.80 Failed to create target binding for binding  for SignatureClickCommand
04-16 17:40:43.731 I/mono-stdout(27727): MvxBind:Warning: 23.80 Failed to create target binding for binding  for SignatureClickCommand
```

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

In typical fashion, left it for an hour and realised my mistake.

I was being lazy by typing:

```
var signatureButton = signatureCard.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_basecard_footer).Text = "Capture"
```

Which was confusing the binding. Switched to:

```
var signatureButton = signatureCard.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_basecard_footer);
signatureButton.Text = "Capture";
```

And it works perfectly

Comment: You also might want to look at https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android
The ViewPageIndicator of Cheesebaron is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

An updated example using TabView and ViewPager is  available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

It uses the latest stuff from the Android design libraries.